# Google Chrome Dev Tools console "undefined" message upon typing the clear() function

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am getting an "undefined" message upon typing the clear() function in google chrome console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clear() function will not work when preserve log is enabled.
We need to uncheck the option "Preserve Log" on console tab
(or)
go to settings -> general -> console -> uncheck "Preserve log upon navigation".

Comment: That seems like a bug to me... [Opened a report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=595208) to see if we can't get that fixed.